# Resize a window to exceed the resolution boundary under X

Tags: linux, window, xlib

I know users can move a window around and make it partially outside of the resolution boundary under X window system. Is it possible to change the size to achieve the same result either programmatically or manually?

[image]

Here is my experimental code, but it doesn't work.

```
        Window w;
        int revert_to;
        XGetInputFocus(m_display, &w, &revert_to);
        if (w == None) {
            printf("can't get focused window");
        }
        else {
            Window top = get_top_window(m_display, w);
            XWindowAttributes xwa;
            XGetWindowAttributes(m_display, top, &xwa);
            XClassHint xch;
            XGetClassHint(m_display, top, &xch);
            printf("focused window name: %s pos: %d, %d size: %d, %d", xch.res_class, xwa.x, xwa.y, xwa.width, xwa.height);
            XResizeWindow(m_display, top, 900, 1900);
        }
```

get_top_window is some codes from internet

```
Window get_top_window(Display* d, Window start) {
Window w = start;
Window parent = start;
Window root = None;
Window *children;
unsigned int nchildren;
Status s;

printf("getting top window ... \n");
while (parent != root) {
    w = parent;
    s = XQueryTree(d, w, &root, &parent, &children, &nchildren); // see man

    if (s)
        XFree(children);

    if(xerror) {
        printf("fail\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("  get parent (window: %d)\n", (int)w);
}

printf("success (window: %d)\n", (int)w);

return w;
```

}

Take terminal as an example, this code could change the inner window but the outline window with titlebar is not affected. is this because the outline window is generated by window manager? And how could I resize it as one unit?

Apart from that, I also can't resize the window out of the resolution boundary. Any solution?

**Edit:** I use compiz window manager and there is no corresponding setting in Compiz configuration settings manager.

**Edit:** With the settings in this [link](http://earlruby.org/2012/04/getting-rid-of-self-resizing-windows-in-ubuntu-linux-12-04/), I'm able to resize a window out of the screen resolution by using mouse middle button click and drag trick. But programmatical method is still not working.

Comment: The application that could be interferring is the **window manager**.   It has the power to allow or don't allow to resize windows.  You have to check your window manager configuration to see if it allows it.  Try to kill your window manager and retry the command to see if it's getting the window size (or placement) as you define.  The thing you have drawn above is common X11 usage, so it's allowed by almost all window managers, it should be no problem to partially obscure a window over the parent window boundaries.

Comment: @LuisColorado
I updated my question. In the picture I drawn, I know A to A' is possible, but I'm not sure about B to B' by just resize the window. It won't allow my cursor out of the screen.

Comment: B to B' is also possible, you can have even A'' completely outside from parent's frame (and completely obscured).  The only limitation is the coordinate system in X11, which is a `short int` and allows a window to be placed only between `-32768` and `+32767`.  Normally, the window manager imposes restrictions to the placement of windows.  They normally don't allow a window to be placed completely outside from the root window frame, as you would get it out of control.  But the X server doesn't impose any restriction to the geometry of a window.

Comment: your cursor cannot go out of the screen, but your windows can.

Comment: @LuisColorado
Thanks for your reply. Is there any way I can bypass window manager? Or is the only solution be configuring window manager to allow it?

Comment: Yes, you can add some flag to the request to the server to bypass the window manager, but I think it's only a hint.  Window managers are free to honor or to ignore your flag.  I have no access to my documentation now.  I cannot add much more information to what we have exchanged now.