# Set cursor position out of resolution under X system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cursor, xlib

Is it possible to programmatically set the cursor position out of the current resolution?

OS: Ubuntu 14
Window manager: Compiz
Resolution: 1920 * 1080

```
XWarpPointer(display, None, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1090);
```

The code above can only move cursor to the bottom edge.

Answer (score 1):

[`XWarpPointer`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XWarpPointer.html) has at least one documented limitation (which may affect your program):

> Note that you cannot use `XWarpPointer()` to move the pointer outside the confine_to window of an active pointer grab. An attempt to do so will only move the pointer as far as the closest edge of the confine_to window.

The likely reason for wanting to move the *pointer* off-screen is to hide it.  An X application can define a *cursor* using [`XDefineCursor`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/XDefineCursor.html) (which is used for displaying the pointer), and hide *that*.  This is for a given window, of course.

[`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) does that, for instance, since [patch #230](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_230) ("hide the mouse pointer while user is typing").

Here are a few links using or discussing the technique:

- [LinuxMouse.cpp](http://foreverwar.sourceforge.net/LinuxMouse.cpp), source-code
- [Platform_Linux.cpp](http://people.eecs.ku.edu/~miller/Courses/773/InClass/Oculus/Linux_Platform.cpp), source-code
- [How to hide the mouse pointer?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.windows.x/HzzhqDKH4is), discussion on comp.windows.x
- [The Cursor](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/cse/classes/cse500/su98/cursor&keys.ppt), a set of slides for a class
- [Basic Graphics Programming With The Xlib Library - Part II](http://neuron-ai.tuke.sk/hudecm/Tutorials/C/special/xlib-programming/xlib-programming-2.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The reason I want to move a cursor offscreen is to simulate scale a window out of screen. Probably I'm trying to solve it in a wrong way. Here is my other question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341668/resize-a-window-to-exceed-the-resolution-boundary-under-x

Comment: I see - but XWarpPointer seems to be the only function to use, and it is documented that it cannot move the pointer out of the window.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, probably this is a dead end. I will try to other approaches.